# How to store data for continous location data

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-location

I've created a simple app which reads location data (latitude, longitude, speed, altitude) every few seconds using `GooglApiClient`. I would like to record the data, so that I would be able to calculate and show: distance, average speed, min and max altitude, trace on the map etc. in real-time to the user. Which data storing method would be the best for this purpose? I don't want to see the implementation of this method from you, just want to know which method would be the best. I was thinking about sqLite database, but isn't it too slow and energy consuming for continous read-write operations.

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I think you need to know more about how much data you are going to be recording (how long are you tracking) what you need to do with the data (all remote or posting to servers, etc.) and what sort of devices are you targeting.  I think your two options are either Sqlite or storing as a file.  Both these options should be fine from a power and speed point of view, the main power issue will be you accessing the GPS sensor, not writing to db or file.

If you chose to write to a file, there are a least 3 (and there are many more) useful formats you can stream a file to that you should be aware of.  They are:

[GPS Exchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) this is an open standard used by many commercial gps and satnav applications which is used to describe waypoints, tracks, and routes

[Geography Markup Language](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml) which is an open xml standard for expressing geographical features which is understood by almost all GIS applications

[GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) which is a standard for describing geographical features in json, which is easy then to render in a web browser.

If you need to you could easily serialize from a Sqlite data set to these file fomats for data interchange.  One thing about streaming to files on Android devices.  However you write your file writer, it may get arbitrarily destroyed by the OS due to memory conditions or user priorities.  This could well mean you end up with malformed files with streams not closed.  This is a lot less likely to happen if you are writing to data tables.

Answer (score 2):

There are four ways to store data in Android that I know of:

- SQLite tables.
- Shared preferences (key-value pairs essentially).
- Creating a `File` in the storage area.
- Serializing an object to a `String` and storing it as a key-value pair.

For your purpose I'd say that the best way to go is creating SQLite tables. Say that your custom `Location` object holds `latitude` and `longitude`, among other things. So if these `Location` objects are converted into rows in a table, then its possible for you to easily retrieve the entire columns of these two data types, i.e. all the position data for every one of the stored `Location` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think sqLite is good enough for you to store location data on every few seconds. You can also buffer data in memory for a short time and write them into sqLite once to reduce I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

Using a SQLite database can be the easiest and safest way to store location data, but you have to be aware that writing to a database blocks read operations.

> Before modifying the database, the writer implicitly acquires an
>   exclusive lock on the database which prevents readers from accessing
>   the database until the write is completed.

For this reason, continuous writing to a database can cause problems and have influence on performance of your application.

You can avoid those problems by **enabling Write-Ahead Logging** which allows reads to proceed concurrently.

Read more on:

- https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

Answer (score 1):

Taking in account the context of your task, I would *not* stick to Android's SQLite. Since you're using just a bunch of primitives as opposed to a set of fully pledged POJOs, spinning up SQLite's database helper, defining schema and dealing with queries is quite a big overhead.

I'd recommend to take a look at [SnappyDb](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB) library which is key-value database.

Either might you deal with each of your primitive values separately or wrap them into a POJO, SnappyDB can handle both cases. If you choose the first way, there are handy methods to query for multiple keys: [keys search](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB#keys-search).

Also, SnappyDB is much faster than SQLite (see benchmarks on their page). And easy to set up, just couple of lines of code.

Hope it helps.